# Validar eventos y visualizar al momento en full calendar

Tags: javascript, django, postgresql

tengo un calendario de reservas el problema que tengo es el siguiente: con una URL y vista guardo los eventos. para poder mostrar los eventos tengo otra URL como una vista para la misma.

Y lo que quiero realizar es que al momento de guardar los eventos que se me puedan mostrar en el mismo calendario. Se los agradecería mucho

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

> full calendar

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendario').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                  left: 'prev,next today',
                  center: 'title',
                  right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth,listWeek,listDay'
            },
            allDay: false,
            defaultDate: new Date(),
            locale: 'es',
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',//hace una vista a la semana del calendario
            navLinks: true,
            weekNumbers: true,
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            timezone: 'UTC',// revisarrrrrrrr
            displayEventTime: true, //quita la hora del evento
            events: [
                {% for i in events %}
                {
                    title: "{{ i.id_cliente}}",
                    start: '{{ i.inicio|date:"Y-m-d HH:mm" }}',
                    end: '{{ i.fin|date:"Y-m-d HH:mm" }}',

                },  
                {% endfor %}
           ],
  
          selectable: true,
          selectHelper: true,
          select: function(startDate, endDate) {
          $('#fc_create').click();
                    alert('selected ' + startDate.format("h:mm") + ' to ' + endDate.format("h:mm"));
                    $("#fecha_inicio").val(startDate.format("h:mm"));                    
                    $("#fecha_fin").val(endDate.format("h:mm"));
                    $("#fecha").val(startDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
                    //horas inicio y fin separadas de la fecha, despues sumarlas y cargarlas al form
                    var hora_inicio = $('#fecha_inicio').val();
                    var hora_fin= $("#fecha_fin").val();
                    var fecha = $('#fecha').val();
                    var hora_inicio = fecha +' '+ hora_inicio;
                    var hora_fin = fecha +' '+ hora_fin;

                    $('#id_inicio').val(hora_inicio);
                    $('#id_fin').val(hora_fin);  
                  },
        });
    });
</script>
```

> Vistas

```
def guardar_reserva(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Reservacion_form(request.POST)
    print (form.errors)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        print ('sii')
        return redirect('eventos')
else:
    form = Reservacion_form()
return render(request, 'canchas/cancha_cesped.html', {'form':form})


def event(request):
all_events = Reserva.objects.all()
if request.GET:       
    event_arr = []
    for i in events:
        event_sub_arr = {}
        event_sub_arr['id_cliente'] = i.titulo
        start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(i.inicio.date()), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
        end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(i.fin.date()), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
        event_sub_arr['inicio'] = inicio
        event_sub_arr['fin'] = fin 
        event_arr.append(event_sub_arr)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(event_arr))
else:
    form = Reservacion_form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        print ('sii')
        return redirect('eventos')

context = {
    "events":all_events,

}
return render(request, 'canchas/cancha_cesped.html',context)
```

> urls

```
url(r'^reserva/', login_required(guardar_reserva), name=''),
url(r'^ver_calendario/', event, name='eventos'),
```

Answer (score 1):

Al tener los eventos construidos desde el servidor, necesitas actualizar la pagina para mostrar los eventos una vez añadidos.
Te recomendaría coger los eventos desde el servidor, según la documentación puedes hacer:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  events: '/getEvents' //donde esta url te dará un JSON con los eventos
});
```

Y luego actualizar una vez añadido:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

Claro para ello necesitas crear una nueva pagina o una nueva funcion donde te devuelva el JSON con los eventos.